# Survivable networks, directed case

Tags: reference-request, network-modeling

I have been working on a project that turns out to be a special case of the directed version of the survivable network problem.

Iterative rounding gives a 2-approximation of the undirected case. I'm wondering if the directed case has been studied at all and if so, what approximations can be guaranteed.

Comment: It would be helpful if you described what the survivable network problem is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The directed versions are much harder. A survey by Nutov available on his web page is 
a good starting point. 
http://www.openu.ac.il/home/nutov/Survivable-Network.pdf